# while refreshing a register page, why is adding empty row in table. even didn't fill the form

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql, forms

here my code that I have problem with which I mentioned. I tried many times to solve this problem but every time its didn't work. can any one told me whats wrong with this code.

```
include("db\db_connection.php");


if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

    $name1 = $_POST['fname'];
    $name2 = $_POST['lname'];
    $dob = $_POST['dob'];
    $number = $_POST['pnum'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $password = $_POST['psw'];
    $confirm = $_POST['repsw'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO user(user_fname, user_lname, DOB, user_phone_number, user_email, user_password)
VALUES('$name1', '$name2', '$dob', '$number', '$email', '$password')";


    if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {

        echo "Inserted data";

    } else {

        echo "couldn't insert data

}
mysqli_close($con);
```

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com), and you have syntax errors in the PHP code. plus, don't output fixed/unchanging error messages. they're useless for debugging. have `die(mysqli_error($con))` instead, so you can be told if/why the query failed.

Comment: The $_POST array will post even if it's not filled.

Comment: `if(!mysqli_query($con, $sql)) {` Isn't this condition totally wrong? Its like echoing inserted while not inserting.

Comment: I have fixed it thanks for the excellent advise

Answer (score 0):

In addition of Marc B comment, better do it like:

```
if(isset($_POST['Submit'])) {

$name1 = $_POST['fname'];
$name2 = $_POST['lname'];
$dob = $_POST['dob'];
$number = $_POST['pnum'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['psw'];


$servername = "server";
$username = "user";
$password = "password";
$dbname = "dbname";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO user (user_fname, user_lname, DOB, user_phone_number, user_email, user_password) VALUES ('$name1', '$name2', '$dob', '$number', '$email', '$password')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
echo "Inserted";

} else {
echo "Not Inserted";

}

mysqli_close($conn);

}
```

Comment: I'm thinking this should be moved to the comment section.